# Multiple login pages Spring

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've been looking for the best way to do this for a while, but haven't found an answer yet.

So in general terms, what's the best way to have multiple login pages (not only forms but controller access) using spring mvc + spring security.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up two http elements in you config file. And set the url patterns in it.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306063/multiple-login-forms-different-authentication-managers-latest-spring-security) answer might help.

Answer (score 0):

<security:authentication-manager id="adminAuthManager">

<security:authentication-manager id="memberAuthManager">

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).