# Spring Security 3.1 - Multiple Authentication Managers - Execute an action depends on the method succeeded

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-ldap

I have this on my app-security.xml, and I want to do some tasks if the user was logged in LDAP, other tasks if the user was logged in DB, etc.

```
    <ldap-server url="ldap://192.168.0.55:389/dc=fluxit,dc=com,dc=ar"
                   manager-dn="uid=admin,ou=system" 
                   manager-password="infra123" 
  />


    <authentication-manager>

        <authentication-provider user-service-ref='databaseAuthManager'>
            <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
        </authentication-provider>

        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
            <user-service id="textFileAuthManager" properties="classpath:auth/users.properties" />
        </authentication-provider>

        <ldap-authentication-provider
            user-search-filter="(uid={0})" user-search-base="ou=users"
            group-search-filter="(uniqueMember={0})" group-search-base="ou=groups"
            group-role-attribute="cn" role-prefix="ROLE_">
        </ldap-authentication-provider>


    </authentication-manager>
```

Can I do that in Spring? I've been Googling for a while and didn't find the answer.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you have different pages for different users (I mean by their source: DB, properties, LDAP)?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306063/multiple-login-forms-different-authentication-managers-latest-spring-security

Answer (score 1):

I think the difficulty with your requirement is that the authentication manager doesn't retain the information which particular authentication provider was the one that actually authenticated the request. If you had that piece of information, you could easily write a custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` to implement some behavior that depends on the authentication method that succeeded.

If you really need this functionality, here is one possible solution I could come up with: Implement a custom `ProviderManager`, that would wrap the authentication object with a decorator that saves a reference to the successful authentication provider. Since the implementation of `ProviderManager` doesn't offer extension points you could use for this, you would basically need to copy the whole class to make the required enhancements. Then you would have to rewrite the whole `<authentication-manager>` part of your configuration without using the security namespace, because it doesn't allow you to replace the default `AuthenticationManager` implementation.

This is neither too elegant nor very easy solution, so there might be some better ways to do it.